# SQL query for previous value based on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following columns in a table

```
DATE_TIME , MESSAGE , VALUE , SOURCE , LOT_NAME
```

Value is associated with SOURCE, LOT_NAME and MESSAGE.

I want to return data with following columns

```
DATE_TIME , MESSAGE , NEW_VALUE ,OLD_VALUE , SOURCE , LOT_NAME
```

where new value is the current row value and OLD VALUE is value of same MESSAGE same source but immediate previous batch vale.

How do I achieve this? Please kindly help .

NA

Comment: Is this what you're looking for?  https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/09/22/sql-server-how-to-access-the-previous-row-and-next-row-value-in-select-statement/

Comment: You really need to provide some sample data and expected result. Maybe your looking for LAG LEAD functions

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `lag()`:

```
select t.*,
       lag(value) over (partition by source, lot_name, message order by date_time) as prev_value
from t;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked like  a charm..